# Swippable collection view with collection view layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How can I achieve this type collection view?

[Ref Image](https://prnt.sc/v8nd87)

When user swipe up, cell should move to up.

I have searched a lot and tried many logic, but not able to match same.

Comment: just make it clear i am asking: what will be happen after first cell move up ? Second one will be come up on it ?

Comment: can you use frameworks?

Comment: @zeytin :- yes. If there is only two cell than position will be random, left or right

Comment: @ShivamParmar :- if you have any reference, you can update me i have search a lot but not able to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am attaching link of some frameworks/classes , it's work on almost similar concept. you can use it or take reference from it .

https://github.com/PPacie/SwipingCarousel

https://github.com/Mindinventory/CoverFlow

https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLSwipeableViewSwift

may it will informative for you ...:)

Comment: First library help me more.
I have tried with 2nd and 3rd earlier.
thanks for support.